# Autofill blanks after filtering

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I need to filter my data, then fill the blank cells in column P using data in column F.

For example, there is a blank cell in cell P34, I have to fill that cell using the cell F34. It should be the same row.

```vb
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$BH").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="="
Dim rngLookup As Range
'assume data that will fill blanks is in column F
With Sheet1
    '  Set rngLookup = .Range(.Range("F2"), .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set rngLookup = .Range(.Range("F2"), Sheet1.Range("F" &.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
With Sheet1
    Dim rngSearch As Range
    'assume blank cells are in column P
    Set rngSearch = .Range(.Range("P2"), .Range("P" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set rngSearch = rngSearch.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    Dim cel As Range, P As Integer
    P = 1
    For Each cel In rngSearch
        cel.Value = rngLookup.Cells(P, 1)
        If P = rngLookup.Rows.Count Then P = 1 Else: P = P + 1
    Next
End With
```

It fills the data from cell F2 onwards.
I need to fill the blanks coming from the same row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the cell equal the F row cell

```
    Sub FillBlank()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    Set rng = Columns("P:P").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        c = c.Offset(, -10)
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: works perfectly, i did not know about the offset. THank you so much!

Comment: ++ You can do away with the loop as well and populate across the value directly :)